# Power 4.8V servo with 5V?

Tags: voltage, power, motor, servo

I would like to use an [HS-5035HD](https://www.terraelectronica.ru/show_pdf.php?pdf=%2Fds%2Fpdf%2F3%2F35035.pdf) in one of my projects. Unlike most servos I've worked with that run at 4.8V-6V, this tiny motor only runs at 4.8V.

I have a 5V regulator in my circuit for powering my microcontroller and it would be great if I didn't need a second regulator. I'm wondering if there will be any actual detriment to running this motor at 5V instead of 4.8V of if 0.2V is within the motor's tolerance.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but a quick Google of several servo suppliers suggests to me that 4.8V should not be exceeded. Probably due to the electronics rather than the motor. You could probably drop that 200mV with a diode or clamp it with a 4.8V Zener rather than trying to find a regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RC servos are designed to be powered by a 4 cell Nicad/NiMH battery pack, which has a *nominal* voltage of 4.8V. Nixx cells charge up to about 1.4V each, so a servo rated for 4.8V 'only' (ie. has no specs for 6V or higher) must be able to handle at least 5.6V (4x1.4V).

In practice a '4.8V' battery pack is only 4.8V when almost flat. Over most of the discharge it is between 5.0 and 5.5V. When an RC system is powered by a higher voltage it typically uses a 5V regulator to power the receiver and servos.

> I have a 5V regulator in my circuit for powering my microcontroller
>   and it would be great if I didn't need a second regulator.

The voltage is fine. However you might still want to use a separate regulator to prevent the servo from injecting noise into the MCU's power supply. The HS-5035HD draws 350mA at stall, so your regulator must be able to handle that as well as whatever current is required to power the MCU and any other support circuitry.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could I use a capacitor to combat any noise generated by the motor?

Comment: Yes. A large (100~1000uF) low ESR electrolytic provides a reservoir for current pulses. Analog servos need higher capacitance because they pulse the motor at lower frequency (~50Hz vs several kHz). Some servo current tests here:- http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/Servo.html

Comment: Thanks, this servo is digital though, would I still need a similar capacitor?

Comment: Perhaps not, but it wouldn't hurt. If your MCU misbehaves when operating the servo then you know you need it!

Answer (score 3):

If you read the data sheet into the first few lines, you'll see it gives 2 sets of specifications.

Don't be alarmed by the line that says 'ONLY 4.8v' because that applies to the specifications in that column. Those are the figures when supplied with 4.8v.

In the box to the right, it says 'at 6v/reference' where it gives another set of specifications, with higher torques and apparently lower speeds. The word reference suggests that's where it's intended to be used. Why does the speed over 60 degrees collapse from 0.1s to 0.8s at the higher voltage? It probably doesn't, a pound to a penny says it's a misprint for 0.08s.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but on the hitec website, it seems to indicate that 6V is not supported. The datasheet also indicates that the 6V test is "for reference only."

http://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/micro-and-mini-servos/digital-micro-and-mini-servos/hs-5035hd-digital-ultra-nano-servo/product